# Should I use spin_lock or mutex_lock for this particular situation?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, spinlock

In my Linux app, I have two threads that both try to send a `UDP` broadcast packet (around 50-500 bytes) using the same `UDP` client socket. They do this about once every 2-3 seconds. In this case, around the "send(...)" clause, I could put `pthread_mutex_lock` or `pthread_spin_lock`.  Theory says that if it's a very small operation, a `pthread_spin_lock` is more efficient (despite high CPU consumption for that small amount of time).  But if its a larger operation, then `pthread_mutex_lock` is better.

Is sending a `UDP` packet considered "small enough" to warrant using a `pthread_spin_lock`,  or should I still stick with `pthread_mutex_lock`?

Thanks

Comment: Are the two threads sending out the same type of packet? Must both packets be sent or could the one thread that finds the channel occupied just skip the transmission?

Comment: @Jens: Yes, both threads send out same type of pkt (same header and some variable amount of data) .. transmission cannot be skipped.

Comment: @All-Others: Thanks for all the answers.  All seem to address the case of syscall like send(). A more generic question would then be: Is there any case for using spinlocks in user space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only need for locking is because they're both sending on the same socket, then there's no need for locking at all - it's acceptable for two threads to call `send()` on the same UDP socket at the same time.  The data sent won't be interleaved.

Answer (score 1):

What you avoid by using a spinlock instead of a mutex is to avoid to go into a syscall in case of a congestion. If you are using the network layer in your critical section, your will be going into a syscall, anyhow. So as far as I can see, using a spinlock makes not much sense, here.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping a system call in a spinlock is a bad idea. The merits of using spinlocks in a user-space app is questionable in any case. The mutex implementation for Linux (using [futexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex)), is very efficient - particularly when a lock is uncontested, which should almost always be the case in well-designed MT apps.

Others have pointed out that the `send` function is itself thread-safe.